# Problem when I dockerize my Angular application

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My problem is that I cna't see my application on the broswer (http://localhost:1999/),
My docker command are this:
docker-compose build
docker-compose up

I'm doing something wrong? Why can't I see my application running?
I tried to add the CMD line with ng -serve but it give me the error that ng isn't istalled, any other suggest?

My docker console:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.1
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 11.2.1 20220219 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 36
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 37
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 38
2022/08/26 13:47:26 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 39
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod
EXPOSE 1999
#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8" 
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
  web:
    build: ./PersonBE/src/main/resources/person-fe
    ports:
      - 1999:1999
  api:
    build: ./PersonBE
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
volumes:
  person:
```

My content in dist:

[image]

My browser:

[image]

Comment: Why do you install node and nginx in the same Dockerfile? They are not supposed to run within the same container. Also 40 workers for local dev is draining your performance for no reason. Make sure the node app is running on the specified port 1999.

Comment: Hi @DanielW. I followed a tutorial online because is the first time I use docker, do you suggest me to take off the nginx:alpine line? and anything else?

Comment: @DanielW. because it's a multi-stage build. node is used to build the app, nginx is used at runtime to serve te app

Comment: @DanielW. so do I keep node right?

Comment: yes keep node and nginx

Comment: Do you have log output from npm install and build? The files inside the container are not the files in your vscode. Go inside the container and check the files and folders in `/app/dist` using something like `docker exec -it web /bin/shell`.

Comment: @DanielW.  BTW I solved by running this command on the console:
"docker build --rm -f person-fe/Dockerfile -t person-fe:latest person-fe"and: "docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 person-fe:latest", do you know how can I do dirrectly this commans with docker-compose or dockerfile??

Comment: @Sonn its compulsory to create docker-compose file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a multistage build. The port exposed is the nginx port (80) not the node port 1999 (the line `EXPOSE 1999` is useless here)

Try :

```
[...]
  web:
    build: ./PersonBE/src/main/resources/person-fe
    ports:
      - 80:80 # port mapping like the command "docker run -d 80:80 person-fe:latest" will do
[...]
```

Next open : http://localhost:80 or http://localhost

Also, your app is generated in the `/app/dist/person-fe` so you must COPY the content of this folder in nginx folder with `COPY --from=node /app/dist/person-fe /usr/share/nginx/html` :

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod
EXPOSE 1999
#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/person-fe /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: I can see it starts nginx but It can't find my angular endpoint

Comment: when you run `npm run build --prod` what is the content of the generated `dist` folder?

Comment: are:
-dist
 -person-app
   -assets
 -index.html
 -runtime...

Indeed I cannot see my componets, is that normal?

Comment: I don't understand your reply but if you used `COPY --from=node /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html`, nginx is just showing up the content of this dist folder. If the content is not as you expect it won't work.

Comment: hi update my question, anyway I don't really know how it works but in the dist folder doesn't appear my angular components, is that normal?

Comment: BTW I solved by running this command on the console:
"docker build --rm -f person-fe/Dockerfile -t person-fe:latest person-fe"and: "docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 person-fe:latest", do you know how can I do dirrectly this commans with docker-compose or dockerfile??

Comment: You can do the same as `docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 person-fe:latest` in docker-compose with a correct port mapping : see my updated response

Comment: Hi Sebastian still sorry for bother you, when I have my application runnig the first thing that I got in url is this: localhost:80/public but when update the page it gives me error and I have to write: localhost:80 to make it work. even if I want to go to another existing endpoint it gives me error, do you know how may I solve this?